# Which material should be chosen for EMI shielding?

Tags: emi-filtering

Once while making a machine with a Hall effect sensor, I had chosen a mild steel (MS), powder coated body for the machine.

Now I am not blaming the MS body until better scientific proof presents, but something changed between the time the raw open machine prototype stood on my table and the time the final product within its metal box arrived: I started experiencing serious electromagnetic inductance (EMI) issues.

My hunch is that a new transformer had come up close by which could have been contributing. That issue was solved with some tinkering in the electronics but that had me thinking: What would be a better casing to help avoid EMI, metal or plastic?

I have been thinking of using plastic next, but I have had a Philips radio in my mum's kitchen which is cased in plastic and which goes crazy if we switch a particular tube light on.

What's the best practice standard operating procedure (SOP) regarding casing for machinery and instruments?

Comment: I'm assuming MS is not microsoft here, so what is it?

Comment: @Hearth done :)

Comment: What frequency band are we talking about?  Are you a victim of EMI or the source?  Are your panels properly bonded?  How big are any gaps?

Answer (score 1):

Hall effect sensors are generally used to sense lowish frequency magnetic fields.

To fully shield against LF magnetic interference, you want thick soft iron outer shielding (high saturation level) to divert the bulk of the interfering field, with inner mu metal shielding (very high permeability) limiting remaining field levels.

Mild steel will provide some degree of magnetic shielding, but depending on precise composition and mechanical treatment, can be magnetically hard are lead to persistent magnetic fields (which may or may not be an issue).

For general higher frequency shielding, E-field is much more of an issue, and you use high electrical conductivity shielding, with no gaps longer than 1/4 minimum wavelength you need to shield against.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be a better casing to help avoid EMI, metal or plastic?

Depends on what kind of EMI needs to be blocked and what frequency. If you are dealing with a DC component (offset), then it's likely the steel got magnetized somehow. If it's an AC noise, try to find the frequency of the noise and eliminate the source, look at motors and transformers. If that can't be done magnetic fields can be attenuated with certain materials like MuMetal, but only attenuation and that might also block the signal you want to measure.